# Jenkins pipeline - emailextrecipients is empty

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

Please note that I'm a beginner working with Jenkins, so I might have missed something obvious.

I'm trying to use the Email-ext plugin in my Jenkins pipeline setup, but I do not seem to be able to retrieve any recipients.

Running the following code in my Jenkinsfile

```
echo  emailextrecipients([
    [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
    [$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
    [$class: 'FirstFailingBuildSuspectsRecipientProvider'],
    [$class: 'FailingTestSuspectsRecipientProvider']])
```

prints nothing, and the send mail code:

```
emailext(
    attachLog: true, 
    body: 'Check console output at "<a href="${env.BUILD_URL}">${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>"', 
    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']], 
    subject: 'FAILED: Job \'${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]\':'
)
```

results in

```
 An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
```

I am able to send example mails, so that seems to be working. Do I need to do anything in the Jenkins setup to define these variables?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you still need an answer but with a colleague we had the same problem and it seems like that our Jenkins was to old and installed the older plugin version.
After updating it manually, it was working.